# starting my second data project and already ran into something I can't figure out

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-wrangling

So I have a table with a column for active covid cases and another one for the city the cases are reported in. Now, I need to somehow sum all the cases for a given state on each day for each state. For example, I have 2 years of daily active covid cases from 100 cities. I would like to put them into "state buckets" for my analysis. Is there a way to do this in R? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Do you have a column for the state name? If not, you can create one, manually. Then you can summarize the results using `dplyr` functions.

Comment: I do have a column name. dplyr summarize should aggregate this data I guess. I did not even think of that. Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this!

Comment: Please include some sample data, perhaps using `dput`, and expected output, along with any approaches that you have tried. In its current state the question can only be answered with a generic response *yes, it is possible*. The specifics depend on the structure of your data (table..? data.frame? character columns? etc.). Additionally, consider rephrasing your title to something that might help future persons to find a solution to a problem.

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse` you can group by the date and state, then use `summarize` and get the `sum` for each day.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(date, state) %>% 
  summarize(sum = sum(active_cases))
```

**Output**

```
  date       state        sum
  <date>     <chr>      <int>
1 2022-01-31 Alabama     6240
2 2022-01-31 New York   10004
3 2022-01-31 Washington  3384
4 2022-02-01 Alabama     6240
5 2022-02-01 New York   10004
6 2022-02-01 Washington  3384
```

**Data Table**

```
dt <- df

setDT(dt)[, sum(active_cases), by = c("date", "state")]

         date      state    V1
1: 2022-01-31    Alabama  6240
2: 2022-02-01    Alabama  6240
3: 2022-01-31   New York 10004
4: 2022-02-01   New York 10004
5: 2022-01-31 Washington  3384
6: 2022-02-01 Washington  3384
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19023, 19023, 19023, 19023, 
                                        19024, 19024, 19024, 19024, 19023, 19023, 19023, 19023, 19024, 
                                        19024, 19024, 19024, 19023, 19023, 19023, 19023, 19024, 19024, 
                                        19024, 19024), class = "Date"), 
                     city = c("Birmingham", "Huntsville", "Mobile", "Montgomery", "Birmingham", "Huntsville", "Mobile", 
                                                                                 "Montgomery", "New York", "Buffalo", "Ithaca", "Long Island", 
                                                                                 "New York", "Buffalo", "Ithaca", "Long Island", "Seattle", "Olympia", 
                                                                                 "Ellensburg", "Spokane", "Seattle", "Olympia", "Ellensburg", 
                                                                                 "Spokane"), 
                     state = c("Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "New York", "New York", 
                                                                                                       "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", 
                                                                                                       "Washington", "Washington", "Washington", "Washington", "Washington", 
                                                                                                       "Washington", "Washington", "Washington"), 
                     active_cases = c(1567L, 2340L, 1039L, 1294L, 1567L, 2340L, 1039L, 1294L, 3980L, 2390L, 2133L, 1501L, 3980L, 2390L, 2133L, 1501L, 567L, 1340L, 384L, 
                                      1093L, 567L, 1340L, 384L, 1093L)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")

         date        city      state active_cases
1  2022-01-31  Birmingham    Alabama         1567
2  2022-01-31  Huntsville    Alabama         2340
3  2022-01-31      Mobile    Alabama         1039
4  2022-01-31  Montgomery    Alabama         1294
5  2022-02-01  Birmingham    Alabama         1567
6  2022-02-01  Huntsville    Alabama         2340
7  2022-02-01      Mobile    Alabama         1039
8  2022-02-01  Montgomery    Alabama         1294
9  2022-01-31    New York   New York         3980
10 2022-01-31     Buffalo   New York         2390
11 2022-01-31      Ithaca   New York         2133
12 2022-01-31 Long Island   New York         1501
13 2022-02-01    New York   New York         3980
14 2022-02-01     Buffalo   New York         2390
15 2022-02-01      Ithaca   New York         2133
16 2022-02-01 Long Island   New York         1501
17 2022-01-31     Seattle Washington          567
18 2022-01-31     Olympia Washington         1340
19 2022-01-31  Ellensburg Washington          384
20 2022-01-31     Spokane Washington         1093
21 2022-02-01     Seattle Washington          567
22 2022-02-01     Olympia Washington         1340
23 2022-02-01  Ellensburg Washington          384
24 2022-02-01     Spokane Washington         1093
```

Comment: Slight typo in `setDT(dt)` as you never defined `dt`. Maybe `dt <- data.table(df)` to keep the original `data.frame`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for catching that! I always create a copy of `df` and name it `dt` when I do `data.table`.

Comment: "Me too" :)  Which is why I glanced for a sec at your `setDT()` example which would work but also alter `df`.  I tend to do such aggregations a lot in `data,table` but keep forgetting base R has us covered, see my alternate answer which apparently was just downvoted (which is how I got back here....)  Thanks again for making `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AndrewGillreathBrown for a sample data set missing from your question.

With the (same) data in a `data.frame` named `df`, we can use base R function `aggregate` to answer this:

```
> aggregate(active_cases ~ date + state, df, sum)
        date      state active_cases
1 2022-01-31    Alabama         6240
2 2022-02-01    Alabama         6240
3 2022-01-31   New York        10004
4 2022-02-01   New York        10004
5 2022-01-31 Washington         3384
6 2022-02-01 Washington         3384
>
```